# Data Binding C# to combo box, list box, text box

Tags: c#, data-binding

I created a program that has 2 lists. Roles (coach, referee, player) and a list of user names. How do I write the data binding elements in the main class? What I am writing is not binding to the controls. I want the combo box to have the drop down option of coach, referee, player. Name entered in the text box, and displayed in the list box.

Member Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    class Member
    {
        string MemberName { get; set; }
        string MemberAddress { get; set; }

        public Member(string memberName, string memberAddress)
        {
            MemberName = memberName;
            MemberAddress = memberAddress;
        }
    }
}
```

Role Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    class Role : List<Member>
    {
        public string MemberRole { get; set; }

        public Role(string memberRole)
        {
            MemberRole = memberRole;
        }

        public List<Member> Members { get { return this; } }
    }
}
```

Main Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<Role> roles = new List<Role>();
            Role role1 = new Role("Member Role");
            role1.Add(new Member("Jay", "Jones"));
            role1.Add(new Member("chris", "cross"));
            role1.Add(new Member("John", "jones"));
            Binding cboBindingSource = new Binding();
            Binding lboBindingSource = new Binding();
            cboBindingSource.Source = roles;
            lboBindingSource.Source = "Roles";
            ComboBox.TextProperty = "Role Name";
            ComboBox = cboBindingSource;
            ListBox.DataContextProperty = lboBindingSource;
            ListBox.DisplayMemberPathProperty = "Member Name";
            textBox.DataContext.ToString("Text", lboBindingSource, "StudentAddress");
        }




    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code

```
ListBox.DisplayMemberPathProperty = "Member Name";
```

should be:

```
ListBox.DisplayMemberPathProperty = "MemberName";
```